# Type of implementation used?

Tags: c++, data-structures, abstract-data-type

There is a question that I have been trying to solve for a while but I'm having difficulty to grasp the correct implementation for it. If we write a program that will manipulate thousands of records, each comprising product name, type, serial number, retail price, etc. In each case below, explain which Abstract Data Type (Queue, Stack, Unsorted and Sorted List) you would use, and which implementation (array or linked structure). Briefly justify your choices.

**1)** Records will be retrieved in the same order they were stored. There is no telling in advance how many records will be processed and how.

- I prefer Unsorted list for this purpose which used linked list implementation because we don't know the number of records at beginning,and data will be retrieved as they are stored hence they must be linked which can also be possible by ADT like Queue or Stack but they use array implementation hence memory allocation problem arises.

**2)** All records will be inserted at the beginning, once and in no particular order. They will be retrieved very frequently, based on serial number.

- Even in the case of printing all the data of records at one time it will be possible with the Unsorted list.

**3)** A large but unknown number of product records will be inserted, as and when needed. They will seldom be retrieved individually. Most operations will consist of processing all records at one go e.g., printing all.

- However here sorted and Unsorted list had more efficiency to use but I prefer Unsorted list because it takes time for sorting which decreases its efficiency.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Hint: list is almost always wrong answer. And your assumption that stack and queue based on arrays is wrong.

Comment: If this is not a textbook / exam question, but a real-world problem, follow Stroustrup's suggestion and start off with vectors. Two words on why: cache effect.

Comment: @lorro It is a textbook problem that I have been solving today.

Comment: BTW not everyone on StackOverflow is a "guy" :)

Comment: @AliShamsi: C++ `std::deque` manages a number of smaller contiguous areas, giving pretty much a best-of-both-worlds hybrid of `list` and `vector` attributes for the needs in 1).  For 2), putting the elements into a `vector` then sorting it by serial number so you can do `std::binary_search`s is good, as is using a `map` or `unordered_map`.  An unsorted list is dreadful as you'll need to search linearly during every retrieval.  3) `vector` has the benefit of contiguous memory / cache locality vs. occasional resizing, while `list` has more predictable insert cost, `deque` is again a good hybrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of what each data structure is intended to do and the access patterns provided in the question and the answers for one and two become self-evident. Three is a bit trickier, but the information you do have is that you have no information about how this data will be used other than the high likelihood that all of it will be used.

## Queue

Queue is a pipe. Stuff goes in one side and comes out the other in the same order (First in, first out, AKA FIFO). You may or may not be able to see anything in the queue other than the item about to come out. In other words, in order to so much as look at the next item in the queue you have to remove the current item. Searching is a very bad idea because likely you can't search it short of taking everything out and putting it all back in again.

## Stack

Stack is just that. A pile of stuff. You put stuff on top of the pile, then you take stuff of the pile. Things come out of the stack in the reverse order to which they were put in. This is first in, last out or FILO. Again, you may not be able to see anything but the top-most item in the stack, so to get at the next item down you have to remove the top item. Searching is a bad idea for the same reason as the queue.

## Unsorted List

Anything could be put anywhere. Putting stuff into the list is a cakewalk because you don't care where it goes. Finding stuff in the list... That's a bummer. You literally have to look at each item one by one (linear search) until you find what you're looking for. If youy don't care what is in the list and never have to search it, this is your data structure. At least until you gather and usage statistics and find some optimizations.

## Sorted list

Everything is in its place according to some specified schema. This makes finding stuff stupidly easy. It's possible that you can go straight to the sought item, and if not you can generally subdivide the list over and over because if the item wasn't on one side of wherever you choose look it must be on the other side (binary search). Finding is easy, but whatever you insert has to be carefully placed and this can be quite expensive. But if you build the list once and then repeatedly search it, you almost always come out ahead.